# Expectation of the product of three (correlated) random variables: E(XYZ)

Tags: probability

I haven't been able to find an answer to this online; please point me in the right direction if that's false!

I have three random variables: $X, Y, \text{and } Z$ with means $\bar{X}, \bar{Y}, \bar{Z}$. They are not pairwise independent. I'm trying to find $E(XYZ)$.

This is what I have done so far: [FWIW this is not a homework problem]

$E(XYZ) = E(XY)\bar{Z} + Cov(XY, Z) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(*)$

Then

$Cov(XY,Z) = E[(XY - E(XY))(Z-\bar{Z})]$

$= E[(XY - \bar{X}\bar{Y} - Cov(X,Y))(Z-\bar{Z})]$

$= E[XYZ - \bar{X}\bar{Y}Z - Cov(X,Y)Z - XY\bar{Z} + \bar{X}\bar{Y}\bar{Z} + Cov(X,Y)\bar{Z}]$

$=E(XYZ) - E(XY)\bar{Z}$

Plugging that back into $(*)$:

$E(XYZ) = E(XY)\bar{Z} + E(XYZ) - E(XY)\bar{Z}$

$\implies 0=0$

Where did my $E(XYZ)$ go?! But yes, I can't seem to find on which line I made what's probably an elementary algebra mistake. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you know only the means of $X, Y, Z$, there is no way of determining $E[XYZ]$. If you know that $X, Y, Z$ are _pairwise_ independent, there is still no way of getting to what you want. As to where $E[XYZ]$ disappeared to, look at what your calculation of the covariance gave you. Can you rearrange it to get (*)?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, thanks. So, just so to be 100% sure I understand you (this is for a very important project to me): there is no way to simplify a general $E(XYZ)$ beyond (*), that is correct?

Comment: Yes, you cannot proceed beyond (*) if all you know are the means _unless_ $X,Y,Z$ are known to be _mutually independent_ (note that _pairwise_ independence is not enough).